# Why can't I re-link a table with vba using the CurrentDB() method directly?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Could anyone explain why the first code example works but the second doesn't?

This re-link code DOES work:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim sNewLinkAddress As String

sNewLinkAddress = "C:\temp\backend.accdb"
Set db = CurrentDb

db.TableDefs("table1").Connect = ";Database=" & sNewLinkAddress
db.TableDefs("table1").RefreshLink
```

This re-link code DOES NOT work, but no error messages are given:

```
Dim sNewLinkAddress As String

sNewLinkAddress = "C:\temp\backend.accdb"

CurrentDb().TableDefs("table1").Connect = ";Database=" & sNewLinkAddress
CurrentDb().TableDefs("table1").RefreshLink
```

What concerns me is that there is a fundamental difference that I'm unaware of between using the Database object directly returned by CurrentDB() and using a variable 'db' that is set to the Database object returned by CurrentDB(). To my mind both ways should be identical, but obviously I'm wrong!

In the past I have used CurrentDB() directly for various things such as opening a recordset with no problem. There seems to be a specific issue with re-linking tables. Any ideas to what's going on here?

I'm using access 2007, but the same issue applies to 2003 also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `CurrentDb()` it returns a new *instance* of the database object.

To illustrate what I mean I'll use letters to represent the database instance (the letters are arbitrary and used only to make it easier to follow the logic).

So in your first example you are using assigning the return value of `CurrentDb` to a database object `db`.  Then each time you call `db` you are referring to the same database object instance:

```
Set db<A> = CurrentDb

db<A>.TableDefs("table1").Connect = ";Database=" & sNewLinkAddress
db<A>.TableDefs("table1").RefreshLink
```

In your second example you make multiple calls to the `CurrentDb` function and each call returns a *different* database object instance:

```
CurrentDb()<B>.TableDefs("table1").Connect = ";Database=" & sNewLinkAddress
CurrentDb()<C>.TableDefs("table1").RefreshLink
```

The upshot here is that when you call `RefreshLink` on the second line you are doing it against a brand new instance of the database object; ie, one whose "table1" Connect property has not been changed.

Comment: For some reason I had always assumed that CurrentDB() returned a pointer to a common instance like a singleton! I must read the documentation more thoroughly in the future.Nicely explained by the way.

Comment: DBEngine(0)(0) returns a pointer to the first database open in the default workspace, which 99.999% of the time is the one open in the Access user interface. However, when a wizard runs, the wizard database becomes DBEngine(0)(0), and so there's a slight chance that it will return a reference to the wrong database. CurrentDB is much safer to use, but you do have to know how to use it. If you look at MS's own code examples, they almost always use it to initialize a database variable and operate on that, instead of directly on CurrentDB.